# How do i let a user insert a link in an input field with normal text?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, web-deployment-project

I am using react.js
I'm trying to build a blog page.
there is a texterea tag to write a blog for the user.
now I want to add the function that allows users to add words that are linked.
so that when i show the text from that input words that are linked are clickable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X7jR.png)
like the blue words in wiki in the image above.
pardon my mistakes (1st question in StackOverflow)

I know about dangerouslysetinnerhtml. but not sure if it's the right way to do so. because then users can modify the code inside (i think). so what is the safe and right way to do so

Comment: Can you show what type of textarea you are using?

Comment: @FarbodShabani <textarea> </textarea>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your case [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) seems best option as it also supports links insertion. For rendering user entered markdown you may use library like [React Markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown). For writing markdown `textarea` is fine as long as you write markdown syntax properly but you may want to consider libraries like [React textarea markdown editor](https://github.com/abelchee/react-textarea-markdown-editor) to make things easier.